# Why does aligning equations not work here?

Tags: align

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\op}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \noalign{$\quad \op{f} * \op{r} = \op{c}_{\op{f}*\op{r}} (x_1,...,x_k) = (\op{f}(a_1,...,a_k), \op{r}(b_1,...,b_k))$}
    &\text{if } x_i=(x^{\op{f}}_i,x^{\op{r}}_i), &\text{then } a_i=x^{\op{f}}_i \in \mathcal{S}, b_i=x^{\op{r}}_i \in (\mathcal{A}^*)^*, &1 \leq i \leq k\\
    &\text{if } x_i \in \mathcal{A}^*, &\text{then } a_i=b_i=x_i, &1 \leq i \leq k
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, "then" should be aligned, too. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried it with `aligned` and `{alignat*}{2}`, but it's not correct there either.

Comment: use `{alignat*}{3}` and change `&\text{then }` to `&&\text{then}`

Comment: I believe that `\op` should not expand to `\operatorname`, but rather to `\mathrm`. Why do you want function names to be upright? Also, never use the `minimal` class for MWEs, prefer `article`.

Comment: @egreg Hmm, somewhere I read that functions are upright and variables italic. As `\sin` etc. If it's not like that, then what's the use having `\operatorname`?

Comment: *Those* particular function names are typeset upright and, in general multiletter function names. Not "normal" functions. `\operatorname` adds spacings that are usually not wanted for single letter function names.

Comment: I think I know what you mean by "normal" functions: every function that is not globally defined in a document but rather used as a variable, like `f \in F` (where F is a set of functions) or in my case also `f * r` as `f` and `r` are just arguments in this scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use a double `&&`:

[image]

The reason is that the `align` and `alignat` environment both provide *pairs* of `rl` aligned equations. So if you want a `l`eft aligned point you need to skip over the `r`ight aligned point.

If you want to control the spacing in between the columns, then use the `alignat` in which case you need to manually add the space. Here I have added a `\quad` for the spacing spacing:

[image]

---

As requested in the comments, here is an alternate use of `align` which ensures that the start of the last two lines is aligned with the first `=` of the first line.

[image]

### Notes:

- A `\phantom{{}={}}` was used to ensure that the last two lines are aligned to the text to the right of the `=`.  The additional `{}` in the `\phantom` is used to ensure proper spacing is applied around the `=`. We could also have use `\hphantom{}` instead, but both will yield identical result in this case.
- `rlap` was used so that the right hand sides is not going to have an effect on the alignment of the subsequent rows.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\op}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|align|:
\begin{align*}
    \noalign{$\quad \op{f} * \op{r} = \op{c}_{\op{f}*\op{r}} (x_1,...,x_k) = (\op{f}(a_1,...,a_k), \op{r}(b_1,...,b_k))$}
    &\text{if } x_i=(x^{\op{f}}_i,x^{\op{r}}_i), &&\text{then } a_i=x^{\op{f}}_i \in \mathcal{S}, b_i=x^{\op{r}}_i \in (\mathcal{A}^*)^*, &&1 \leq i \leq k\\
    &\text{if } x_i \in \mathcal{A}^*, &&\text{then } a_i=b_i=x_i, &&1 \leq i \leq k
\end{align*}
Using \verb|alignat|:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    \noalign{$\quad \op{f} * \op{r} = \op{c}_{\op{f}*\op{r}} (x_1,...,x_k) = (\op{f}(a_1,...,a_k), \op{r}(b_1,...,b_k))$}
    &\text{if } x_i=(x^{\op{f}}_i,x^{\op{r}}_i), &&\quad\text{then } a_i=x^{\op{f}}_i \in \mathcal{S}, b_i=x^{\op{r}}_i \in (\mathcal{A}^*)^*, &&\quad 1 \leq i \leq k\\
    &\text{if } x_i \in \mathcal{A}^*, &&\quad\text{then } a_i=b_i=x_i, &&\quad 1 \leq i \leq k
\end{alignat*}
\hrule\medskip\noindent
Alternate alignment with \verb|align|:
\begin{align*}
    \op{f} * \op{r} &= \op{c}_{\op{f}*\op{r}} (x_1,...,x_k) \rlap{${}= (\op{f}(a_1,...,a_k), \op{r}(b_1,...,b_k))$}\\
    &\phantom{{}={}}\text{if } x_i=(x^{\op{f}}_i,x^{\op{r}}_i), &&\text{then } a_i=x^{\op{f}}_i \in \mathcal{S}, b_i=x^{\op{r}}_i \in (\mathcal{A}^*)^*, &&1 \leq i \leq k\\
    &\phantom{{}={}}\text{if } x_i \in \mathcal{A}^*, &&\text{then } a_i=b_i=x_i, &&1 \leq i \leq k
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, although I'd rather not use `\quad`s. Is it possible to use `align` with `&&` so that the start of the second and third line is aligned to the first `=` of the first line (without aligning the rest of the first line)?

Comment: @neo: Have updated solution to provide an alternate alignment with `align`.

Answer (score 5):

Peter Grill has already answered your basic problem with the number of ampersands.  However, I would suggest a different approach of introducing an `aligned` environment to contain the second and third lines.  This left hand side of this can then be lined up with the first line using an enclosing `align` environment.  Do this to the right of the equals sign is accomplished by a `= {}&` to correct correct spacing around that sign.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Alignment to left of equals:
\begin{align*}
    f * r &=  c_{f*r} (x_1,...,x_k) = (f(a_1,...,a_k), r(b_1,...,b_k))\\
    &
    \begin{aligned}
      &\text{if } x_i=(x^f_i,x^r_i), &&\text{then } a_i=x^f_i
      \in \mathcal{S}, b_i=x^r_i \in (\mathcal{A}^*)^*,
        &1 \leq i \leq k,\\ 
      &\text{if } x_i \in \mathcal{A}^*, &&\text{then } a_i=b_i=x_i,
        &1 \leq i \leq k.
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

Alignment to right of equals:
\begin{align*}
    f * r = {}&  c_{f*r} (x_1,...,x_k) = (f(a_1,...,a_k), r(b_1,...,b_k))\\
    &
    \begin{aligned}
      &\text{if } x_i=(x^f_i,x^r_i), &&\text{then } a_i=x^f_i
      \in \mathcal{S}, b_i=x^r_i \in (\mathcal{A}^*)^*,
        &1 \leq i \leq k,\\ 
      &\text{if } x_i \in \mathcal{A}^*, &&\text{then } a_i=b_i=x_i,
        &1 \leq i \leq k.
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

I have taken advantage of the comments to the question to remove the `\op` commands.

Comment: I accepted the other answer as it answered the original question already, but +1 for your answer, I really like it. No hackery and very logical.