# Where is this whitespace coming from in align*?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am trying to align 2 simple equations using the `align*` environment:

```
\begin{align*}
\phi(\gedge{\tilde{v}_{i_1}}{\tilde{u}_i}) & = \phi(\gedge{\tilde{v}_{i_2}}{\tilde{u}_i}) & = \gedge{v}{u} \\
\phi(\gedge{\tilde{u}_i}{\tilde{v}_{i_1}}) & = \phi(\gedge{\tilde{u}_i}{\tilde{v}_{i_2}}) & = \gedge{u}{v} & \qquad\mathrm{(z\,wl.\,2)}\\
\end{align*}
```

unfortunately the result I am getting is horrible:

[image]

Why is there so much horizontal space before the second `=` sign?!?

Do not worry about `\gedge`, it is just an arrow:

```
% graph edge
\newcommand{\gedge}[2]{%
#1 \to #2%
}%
```

Comment: With align, you need only one `&`.  If you want to use multiple alignment spots, you can use the `alignat` environment.

Comment: related, if not exactly the same: [Why does aligning equations not work here?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83658/579)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have two options,

1. Using align

   ```
   \begin{align*}
   \phi(\gedge{\tilde{v}_{i_1}}{\tilde{u}_i}) & = \phi(\gedge{\tilde{v}_{i_2}}{\tilde{u}_i}) = \gedge{v}{u} \\
   \phi(\gedge{\tilde{u}_i}{\tilde{v}_{i_1}}) & = \phi(\gedge{\tilde{u}_i}{\tilde{v}_{i_2}}) = \gedge{u}{v}  \qquad\mathrm{(z\,wl.\,2)}\\
   \end{align*}
   ```
2. Using alignat

   ```
   \begin{alignat*}{4}
   \phi(\gedge{\tilde{v}_{i_1}}{\tilde{u}_i}) & = \phi(\gedge{\tilde{v}_{i_2}}{\tilde{u}_i}) && = \gedge{v}{u} \\
   \phi(\gedge{\tilde{u}_i}{\tilde{v}_{i_1}}) & = \phi(\gedge{\tilde{u}_i}{\tilde{v}_{i_2}}) && = \gedge{u}{v} & \qquad\mathrm{(z\,wl.\,2)}\\
   \end{alignat*}
   ```

   > [image: Result]

Comment: The `alignat` solution should really use a double `&&` to get the correct spacing.  See for instance: [Why does aligning equations not work here?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83658/why-does-aligning-equations-not-work-here)

Comment: @PeterGrill or couldnt `{}` be placed too?

Comment: For _this_ specific case a `{}` would suffice, but not a general solution as it would still be `r` aligned, and an `l` aligned is probably what is desired in this case. See question I linked to.

Comment: @PeterGrill Heiko Oberdiek added in `&&` already.