# Alignment of six matrices

Tags: align

I'm currently facing a problem with the `align` environment. I'd like to write six matrices in two rows, aligned on each equal sign per column. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do this with the `align` environment for some reason. I've read the related posts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248196/multiple-matrix-equations-alignment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83658/why-does-aligning-equations-not-work-here), where [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248196/multiple-matrix-equations-alignment)] seems to be a bit of an overkill for my problem and [[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83658/why-does-aligning-equations-not-work-here)] doesn't work for some reason...

An MWE to the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
I _ { 1 } &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 1 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { - 1 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}, 
I _ { 2 } &&=  
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 1 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}, 
I _ { 3 } &&= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 1 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { -1 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}, \\
J _ { 1 } &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix},
J _ { 2 } &&= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { -1} & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix},
J _ { 3 } &&= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { - 1 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ - 1 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Note: I'm aware that most of the `{}` are useless here but the matrices were generated by Mathpix....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just moved the `&`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
I _ { 1 } &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 1 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { - 1 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}, 
&I _ { 2 } &=  
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 1 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}, 
&I _ { 3 } &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 1 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { -1 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}, \\
J _ { 1 } &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix},
&J _ { 2 } &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { -1} & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ -1} & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix},
&J _ { 3 } &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { - 1 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ 
{ - 1 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 0 } 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: David and his movement made me feel good.

Comment: @marmot I didn't look at them (as I say I just moved the `&` ) but what about them?

Comment: @marmot not a sign change between a test file and a supplied example, you are _assuming_ that is the meaning of these matrices:-)

Comment: @marmot TeX takes no position on mathematical accuracy, so long as it looks nice.

Comment: @marmot in that case, which convention do you prefer?^^

Comment: @marmot more seriously it's not my area of mathematics and I didn't recognise these as any particular set of matrices so I took the supplied equation at face value and had no answer to your initial comment of "was I sure about the signs"  If you wish to edit the question and answer to match then feel free.

Comment: @MariusJaeger Anything in which the structure constants for the SO(3) subgroup are given by the Levi-Civita symbol.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. My comment was not meant to be destructive and I had a feeling that special relativity is not your field of maths. It was only a remark that I made when I upvoted your nice answer, knowing it will be read by hundreds of users.

Answer (score 6):

Uniform alignment everywhere...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\begin{document}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\begin{align*}
I _ { 1 } =& 
\parenMatrixstack[r]{
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & { 1 } \\ 
0 & 0 & { - 1 } & 0 
},&
I _ { 2 } =&  
\parenMatrixstack[r]{
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 
}, &
I _ { 3 } =& 
\parenMatrixstack[r]{
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  1  & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
}, \\
J _ { 1 } =& 
\parenMatrixstack[r]{
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
},&
J _ { 2 } =& 
\parenMatrixstack[r]{
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
},&
J _ { 3 } =& 
\parenMatrixstack[r]{
0 & 0 & 0 & { - 1 } \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1  & 0 & 0 & 0 
}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These matrices align nicely because *I* and *J* happen to be about the same width.  But if they had instead been *I* and *M*, the alignment would have been different.  Better to put the "second" `&` before the = sign in each instance.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the great suggestion.  Only clarification is that in TABstackengine, the `&` should, by default, follow the `=` rather than precede it.

Comment: @steven : This solution doesn't compile with overleaf.com, error at line 51.

Comment: @pzorba75 Sorry I cannot assist...I am not an overleaf user.